# Split the list by every 4th element if 5th element is "Name" or split by 5th element if 5th element is Address

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, for-loop

I have a 8000 list of names, company, address1, address2, address3(optional) ina sequence order as shown below. This is a python list

```
[John
It Tech
1243 mary drive
florida-32006
mark
Infotech
1245 lonely drive
irony estate 324
Virginia-24531
Steve
king Electronics
.
.
]
```

The address3 is optional and cant expect it in the sequence every time.name will start next of address2. I need to split the list by every nth element i.e by name checking the 5th element is name or address. If it is address, increment the split by nth+1. If not, continue by 4. I simply want to add these to excel columns.

Below is the code I tried and it splits the list by every 4th element. It ignores if the 5th element is name or address.

```
test2= [final1[x:x+4] for x in range(0, len(final1),4)]
```

This gives me result as

```
[['John','It Tech','1243 mary drive','florida-32006'], 
['mark','Infotech','1245 lonely drive','irony estate 324'],
['Virginia-24531','Steve','king Electronics']] 
** the last list should start from Steve and the address(Virginia-24531) in the previous list***
```

I kindly request someone to please help me with this issue. Thanks you so much in advance

Comment: how to distinguish a name of `'mark'` from a name of `'Virginia-24531'` ? If you solve that you are almost done ...

Comment: btw your list is NOT a python list - it is NameError to be happening ... or SyntaxError ... or anything between.

Comment: How do you distinguish between `name` and `address3(optional)` ?

Comment: I have defined a function to see if it has Numbers or zipcode                              
 `def hasNumbers(inputString):
    return any(char.isdigit() for char in inputString)`

Comment: What does this has to do with dataframes or pandas?

Answer (score 1):

Your adresses seem to contain numbers - *your* names* do not.  You can use that to split accordingly:

```
from string import digits

def splitIt(data):
    i = 0
    tmp = []
    for d in data:
        # the first 4 lines we add without check - datasets have always 4 lines minimum
        if i > 3:            # this will break if you have data with fewer then 4 lines
            if not any(c in digits for c in d):  # if the 5th line has no numbers: NAME
                yield tmp
                tmp = [d]
                i = 1
        else:                                    # else another address line, check 6th
            tmp.append(d)                        # line for name (you can have as many 
            i += 1                               # lines with numbers in it after the 4th)
    yield tmp


data = ["John",       # no number
"It Tech",
"1243 mary drive",    # has number
"florida-32006",      # has number
"mark",               # no number
"Infotech",
"1245 lonely drive",
"irony estate 324",
"Virginia-24531",
"Steve",
"king Electronics",]

print(list(splitIt(data)))
```

Output:

```
[['John', 'It Tech', '1243 mary drive', 'florida-32006'], 
 ['mark', 'Infotech', '1245 lonely drive', 'irony estate 324'], 
 ['Steve', 'king Electronics']]
```

---

Disclaimer: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: your code works awesome. I need a little more help. Sometimes I have country or city Name as the last line that ends before the name. I have all the counties and cities as a list. Will we able to check te value if present in this list  and make increment untill we find a name? so the logic is "If we the value dont have numbers or its not one of the values in the countries list, then split. Its for sure is the name. Thank you so much for the above code. Sorry If I sound foolish. I am dealing with dirty data

Comment: @reddy you might. put them into a set and check them. Problem: some city names could be person names as well:  `'Charlston'`, `'Houston'`, ... - adapt this code to what works :)

Comment: Hi Patrick, Thank you. I will make a set of  cities and countries and check the result. Thanks for your time. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The assumption below is that address has a hyphen and name does not (very dangerous). Then it will cut the first 4 or 5 elements of the list depending if the last entry [-1] is an address or a name.

```
result=[]
for x in range(len(final1)):
    tmp = final1[:5] if len(final1) >= 5 else final1
    if len(tmp)==0:
        break

    if '-' in tmp[-1]:
        result.append(tmp) 
        final1 = final1[5:]
    else:
        result.append(final1[:4])
        final1 = final1[4:]
result

[['John', 'It Tech', '1243 mary drive', 'florida-32006'],
 ['mark','Infotech','1245 lonely drive','irony estate 324','Virginia-24531'],
 ['Steve', 'king Electronics']]
```